# Most of the network is throwing a Runtime error

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange

> #### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ---
>
> ***Runtime Error***
>
> **Description**: An exception occurred while processing your request.
>   Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom
>   error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

[image]

This is happening as I'm posting this question.

Comment: Any site, except meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ is fine too.

Comment: Was just about to report this here as well.  https://i.imgur.com/yWNIDQv.png . Looks like someone didn't run all their unit tests before pushing live ^.^.  It is all sites except this one which are affected.

Comment: Everyone I asked IRL have no issues. QAQ

Comment: Looks like IPS is back up.

Comment: Most of my usual sites seem to work for me ._. MSE's likely unaffected cause (ironically?) its where stuff gets tested first I suspect.

Comment: It's not really back yet, I get "host can't be resolved" every few requests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sub>(copied from my [answer on meta.so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357687/115866))</sub>

The servers where the errors happened just got patched. The running theory is that that in some cases, when app domains that existed *before* that patching tried to load new assemblies *after* the patching, there was some conflict that prevented that from working.

```
Exception type: FileLoadException 
Exception message: Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set
    from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
```

This is so low-level that you didn't even get our [custom error page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311133/how-can-i-see-all-the-images-of-the-error-page/311135#311135) if you hit an affected server (which wasn't all of them, so not everybody saw any issues).

We'll look deeper into the causes later, but the issue is fixed for now and it's late at night for our SREs in the U.S.

Comment: So the "host can't be resolved" I now get often isn't related?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No, that would be a DNS issue (and the usual cause for something like that is a blip in your internet connection).